# Stop carousel when video playing - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating Bootstrap(4) carousel with some videos (not only) and I would like it to stop when video playing (with auto-play) and continue at the end of the video.

I know there is a lot of similar subjects but everything is from 1-3 years ago (bootstrap 3/2) and nothing works right now...

This is my HTML sample code

```
<div id="mediaCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <video autoplay width="100%"><source src="video1.mp4"></video>
         </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="image1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="image2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
</div>
```

An exemple of what i tried and what i saw most of time :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mediaCarousel").carousel({ interval: false}); // this prevents the auto-loop
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
    videos.forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    }); 

    function myHandler(e) {
        $("#mediaCarousel").carousel('next');
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance ! ;)

Comment: Register for each video element a "play/ended" event listener and call in the listener `.carousel('pause')` on play and .carousel('next') on ended

Comment: More info on what Marc mentioned https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices on 2 comments above, and adapting it to your sample code, see below an example:

1 - Set an ID to your video tag (id="video_1")

```
<div id="mediaCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <video autoplay width="100%" id="video_1" ><source src="video1.mp4"></video>
         </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="image1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="image2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
</div>
```

2 - updating javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mediaCarousel").carousel({ interval: false}); // this prevents the auto-loop
    var vid1 = document.getElementById("video_1");
    vid1.onended = function() { $("#mediaCarousel").carousel('next'); };

</script>
```